# Regex in R to match strings in square brackets

Tags: r, regex

I have transcripts of storytellings with many instances of overlapped speech indicated by square brackets wrapped around the speech in overlap. I want to extract these instances of overlap. In the following mock example,

```
ovl <- c("well [yes right]", "let's go", "oh [  we::ll] i do n't (0.5) know", "erm [°well right° ]", "(3.2)")
```

this code works fine:

```
pattern <- "\\[(.*\\w.+])*"
grep(pattern, ovl, value=T) 
matches <- gregexpr(pattern, ovl) 
overlap <- regmatches(ovl, matches)
overlap_clean <- unlist(overlap); overlap_clean
[1] "[yes right]"     "[  we::ll]"      "[°well right° ]"
```

But in a larger file, a dataframe, it doesn't. Is this due to a mistake in the pattern or could it be due to how the dataframe is structured? The first six lines of the df look like this:

```
> head(df)
                                                             Story
1 "Kar:\tMind you our Colin's getting more like your dad every day
2                                             June:\tI know he is.
3                                 Kar:\tblack welding glasses on, 
4                        \tand he turned round and he made me jump
5                                                 \t“O:h, Colin”, 
6                                  \tand then (                  )
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Though it might be working in certain cases, your pattern looks off to me.  I think it should be this:

```
pattern <- "(\\[.*?\\])"
matches <- gregexpr(pattern, ovl)
overlap <- regmatches(ovl, matches)
overlap_clean <- unlist(overlap)
overlap_clean

[1] "[yes right]"     "[  we::ll]"      "[°well right° ]"
```

### Demo

This would match and capture a bracketed term, using the Perl lazy dot to make sure we stop at the first closing bracket.

Comment: Yes. Your pattern is indeed better. And as to to my problem re the df, oh well, I'd just forgotten to specify the column! So that's solved too...

Answer (score 1):

To match strings between `[` and `]` with no square brackets in between use

```
"\\[[^][]*]"
```

It will match `[a]` in `[a[a]` string, unlike the `\[.*?]` pattern.

**Details**

- `\[` - a `[` char
- `[^][]*` - a negated bracket expression (or character class) that matches any 0 or more chars other than `[` and `]`
- `]` - a `]` char (there is no need escaping it outside of a character class/bracket expression)

See the [Regulex graph](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%5C%5B%5B%5E%5C%5D%5B%5D*%5D):

[image]

See the [R demo online](https://ideone.com/vG1dmz):

```
ovl <- c("well [yes right]", "let's go", "oh [  we::ll] i do n't (0.5) know", "erm [°well right° ]", "(3.2)")
unlist(regmatches(ovl, gregexpr("\\[[^][]*]", ovl)))
## => [1] "[yes right]"     "[  we::ll]"      "[°well right° ]"
```

With `stringr::str_extract_all`:

```
library(stringr)
ovl <- c("well [yes right]", "let's go", "oh [  we::ll] i do n't (0.5) know", "erm [°well right° ]", "(3.2)")
unlist(str_extract_all(ovl, "\\[[^\\]\\[]*]"))
## => [1] "[yes right]"     "[  we::ll]"      "[°well right° ]"
```

Here, as the pattern is handled with ICU regex library, you need to escape both square brackets in the regex pattern.